# Should I be worried about the "electron shower" I receive whenever I turn on my 1989 CRT TV?

Tags: safety, consumer-electronics, history

If I stand in front of it when I press the "small power button" (the one which actually turns on the screen, as opposed to the big switch just giving the entire unit power), my big 1989 TV appears to "shower" me with electricity.

I don't feel pain from it, but I definitely *feel* it. As if I'm briefly subjected to radiation or something.

I have begun standing to the side and pressing the button with my finger, as to avoid this. I strongly doubt that it's dangerous, but I still don't feel like I should be subjecting myself to it.

I can't recall the same thing happening on my previous CRTs, but on the other hand, those were made after the year 2000, so they probably are far more advanced and perhaps found a way to eliminate this effect.

It feels sort of like when I pressed the "degaussing" button on my CRT computer monitor from the late 1990s.

Is this dangerous? Normal? Should I avoid standing in front of it when "kickstarting" the screen by pressing the small power button?

Comment: you are probably feeling the static electricity charge on the screen ... walk across a carpet for a similar exlerience

Comment: As I remember , CRT TV has a brief degaussing cycle as they were turned on.

Answer (score 2):

The static electricity generated by old school CRT's is of no consequence to your health.  There is a very small amount of ionizing radiation (xrays) probaly similar at regular distances to standing outside, so you probably shouldn't make one a pillow and sleep on it, but these devices were ubiquitous throughout the word for decades with no ill effects.